# Send file for conversion to least loaded server, based on load and probability(in php)

Tags: php, distribution

I have several ffmpeg processing servers that do conversions of video files. I have a poller that grabs the load averages from these servers, and updates a mysql table with them, every 5 minutes.

I could just say... give me server with lowest load, but the problem with that, in those 5 minutes, it might queue 20 files to be converted on that 1 server, while the other servers which might free up in 10 minutes, will be idle.

So i wanted to add a probability aspect to the selection of the least loaded server, so the least loaded server has a high chance of getting selected, but other servers will still get something.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're doing this backwards. Instead of guessing what server is available to push jobs to based on stale data, queue the jobs and let the servers pull them when they're actually available to work.

Comment: Its a lot less complicated to have 1 job manager that runs on the push side, than many, each one running on the pull side.

Comment: It is one program either way. The complexity is exactly the same. This is how all the conversion-as-a-service companies operate. They spin up more or less worker servers depending on the size of the queue. Each worker is identical and pulls jobs from the queue.

Comment: +1, seems more logical on any point, and there is little to no complication added this way, it is actually _simpler_ IMHO.

Comment: The jobs are fairly complex, they require work in php (thumbnailing, math, etc). With a "controller server", that sends jobs out, it actually does the php work for the conversion servers, and just issues remote commands. Otherwise, Id have to install php and mysql on each server.

Comment: You mean *on one server, which you launch many copies of* :) Welcome to the cloud.